# Structure with an array, is memory contiguous?

Tags: c++, compilation

if I have

```
struct S {
    int a;
    float* b;
    int c;
};
```

Aside from any padding. a, b (the variable where a pointer is kept), and c will be contiguous.
The element that b is pointing to, may be somewhere else in memory

if I have

```
struct S {
    int a;
    float b[10];
    int c;
};
```

a, every element of b, and c will all be contiguous in memory. Correct?
I wrote a test program and looked at the addresses to confirm, but I am not sure if that is the compiler being helpful or it is guaranteed.

Comment: If it's not guaranteed I've written a lot of shaky code.

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: @user4581301 *If it's not guaranteed I've written a lot of shaky code* That sounds suspicious. Well-written code should normally not depend on that different objects are laid out contiguously in memory.

Comment: `a, every element of b, and c will all be contiguous in memory` let's assume for a moment - no matter if it is correct or not - that there is no padding and when asking for the address everything is continuous. It then depends on whether you do something with `S` for which the address is relevant. If the compiler can guarantee that the memory addresses are not relevant, it can optimize the whole or parts of the object away. If you look at the compiled result of [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/r6z8z73bq), you can see that all values of the created `S` are part of the generated instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `a`, (the elements of) `b`, and `c` will be contiguous, if we ignore possible padding between `a` and `b`, or `b` and `c`. Of course there's no padding between the elements of `b`.

Comment: _Of course there's no padding between the elements of b_ That's not true in the general case: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PlBhwb9HOqE9jqVH (just in case anyone is misled by that).

Comment: There can indeed be padding between the elements of the array, if the element type requires padding to satisfy a particular alignment. If the element type is a class/struct type, such padding may or may not appear inside the type itself after all of its data members.

Comment: Nitpick:  Two fields are not contiguous in memory if there is padding between them.  Array elements don't have padding between them so the elements are contiguous.

Comment: @PaulSanders The padding is never *between* the elements, but rather is a part of the element type. It's inserted at the end of the struct regardless of whether it's used as an array element of not. But I guess I'm just splitting hairs on the wording.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ^^^

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Tweaked the wording a bit, should be better now.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, fair enough.  I just didn't want anyone to jump to the wrong conclusions.